# My Asus 7600gt lost output in both connectors

Tags: graphics-card, hardware-failure, nvidia-graphics-card

I'm using an Asus EN7600GT as my video card for a few years now. Like a year ago the secondary DVI output started to malfunction. It didn't send any signal and my secondary monitor (an HDTV) was not recognized. As I didn't use it much I didn't care.
Yesterday when I booted the PC, no signal was sent to the monitor, not even during boot-up (in fact some "shadows" appeared during boot-up, something like slightly lighter horizontal bands over the black background). After some seconds the monitor went off.
Apart from the screen, the computer is starting properly. I can hear Windows starting music and some other normal sounds. I tried the monitor with my laptop and it is working properly, and I also tried connecting the TV through a VGA cable, but it didn't work. I also tried the secondary DVI output without success.
Do you agree with me that the problem should be in the video card? Unfortunately I don't have a spare one to try.
Do you know anything else I can try before buying another card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sure sounds to me like your video card bit the dust.  If it first started acting funny a year ago, I'd almost consider you lucky that it was still usable at all this long.  Yeah, I'd say it's time to get a new video card.  If you want to be *absolutely sure*, try taking the vid card (and your PC) to a local PC shop that can test them for you, or perhaps a friend can swap cards with you temporarily to see if the problem follows the card or your PC.